# Is it possible to view which climable areas can be used by the current animal?

Tags: planet-zoo

While building a climbing area for my gorillas, I found that the traversable area view did not show blue areas for my climbing material. Eventually I figured out through patiently waiting that my gorillas will actually use the climbing platforms I have placed, even though it does not show up.

Is there a view or setting somewhere that allows me to figure out if whatever I am building is climbable in the way I placed it, without having to wait for the animal to actually use it?

[image: A gorilla habitat with "traversable area" toggled on, showing no blue zones on my climbing platforms]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, not directly. What you can do is observe changes to the climbable area value (animal info panel) when you add/remove climbable objects.

To be honest I generally focus on the numbers and quit when they're green - if something is amiss later on I'll notice it and correct it. If I haven't noticed it, then it didn't really matter.

I find that a better approach than trying to divine the fuzzy AI pathing.

Answer (score 1):

Some years and many patches later:

There is no overview that lets you see climbable areas. Traversable area isn't helpful since it only shows where animals can walk, not where they can climb.

The easiest way to check it is to drop one of the intended animals in the shelter and then click on them with the game paused as you build. Just keep in mind that the more animals you put in there, the more space they will require.

Recent patches have also made it possible to make shelters and other buildings climbable, as long as the construction parts forming the building belong to a group. Click on the shelter/building and then check/uncheck "climbing enabled".

Meaning that if you place the gorilla shelter in the middle of the habitat, you can nowadays make the shelter itself count as climbable to save space. It will sate the animal needs for climbable space and shelter both. Though in case you place it close to a habit wall, that also means that they might climb up the shelter and then escape the habit that way.

In one park I wanted a spare habitat where I could place various bachelor male monkeys/lemurs. I used one of the prefab shelters and stacked 2 on top of each other with some manual tweaking, to build a "monkey skyscraper" shelter in the middle. While not being the prettiest, this habitat has some 700m2 climbable area (out of 1821m2 total):

[image]

As you can see, the monkeys are fine with finding the upper levels (using the 4 tall poles I placed in each corner) and may use the upper levels for sleeping too if you place beds there.

And of course if you aren't as lazy as to use prefabs, you can build them 100% custom yourself. Given how flexible the building system is, I think the sky is really the limit for how tall you could make it :)

Works with most bears, leopards etc too, as long as the animal can climb.

Comment: Tree huts on top of some climbable tree(s) might be another option but I haven't tried that. Sounds like it could be pretty awesome if you can get it to work ok (not just counting towards climbable area/shelter but the animals actually using it too).